# Using `Parameters<>` Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I'm trying to "reexport" interface of events to its function parameters:
e.g

```
interface Events {
 init: (value: string) => boolean,
 end: (value: string, anotherValue: string) => void,
}
```

Expected result:

```
interface EventsParams {
 init: [value: string],
 end: [value: string, anotherValue: string],
}
```

What I'm doing:

```
import { Events } from './events';

export declare type EventsParams = {
    [Property in keyof Events]: Parameters<Events[Property]>;
};
```

it is working for me in "dev", but in production I get:

```
error TS2344: Type 'Events[Property]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
  Type '((value: string) => void) | ((value: string) => void) | ((value: string) => void) | ((value: string) => void) | ((value: string) => void) | ((value: string) => void) | ... 75 more ... | undefined' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
     [Property in keyof Events]: Parameters<Events[Property]>;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean `in production` ? Also, why do you use `export declare type`. AFAIK, you need just to write `export type EventsParams = ... `. `declare` usually is used for `*.d.ts` files or to extend some type in third party library. How do you use `EventsParams` type?

Comment: See this for context:
https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/5454

https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/master/src/angular/src/swiper-events.ts

Comment: This code works for me right now, but I'd be happy for explanation and optimization. I dont really understand why this needed:
`
export declare type EventsParams<T = SwiperEvents>  = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? Parameters<T[P]> : never;
};
`

Comment: SOrry, I'm not familiar with this library and I don't know how to reproduce it. You increase your chances to get an answer if you will provide a reproducible example in any sandbox

Comment: Please see [example](https://tsplay.dev/NlgX5w) with explanation. How do you want to optimize it? Do you want to make it less verbose?

Comment: If less verbose, you can try [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVarqw)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!
Last example don't work for me:

Type 'SwiperEvents' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<PropertyKey, Fn>'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'SwiperEvents

Comment: Is `SwiperEvents` is an interface ?

Comment: Could you please share `SwiperEvents` ? If yes, you can't make it less verbose.

Comment: It is interface https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/d679a98ec1b24be9f6ca057e02911e2e7ee91924/src/types/swiper-events.d.ts

Comment: I think it worth leaving this utility type as it is